# upgrading grails 2.2.0 to 2.4 in intelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add a `new global library` to a project. When I click `new global library` button, I select `java` and navigate to the grails installation

[grails 2.4 http://snag.gy/aZuHv.jpg](http://snag.gy/aZuHv.jpg)

I click okay and select a category (any category, i've tried them all) and I get the following and doesn't seem to work

[what the library does look like http://snag.gy/LAFEY.jpg](http://snag.gy/LAFEY.jpg)

this is what it should look like

[what the library should look like http://snag.gy/nYZlz.jpg](http://snag.gy/nYZlz.jpg)

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: i'd rather change it via the gails menu in the project tree (right click root, grails, change sdk, pick the new one).  but with intellij this is all guesswork...

Comment: that helped. I tried adding my grails project that way and I get a `Looks like grails distrubtion in specified path is broken. Cannot determinate version` error message. Now I know it's not IntelliJ but the installation that is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with a right click on your project. Please see attached screenshot. Change SDK

[image]